# How can I put two bars of distinct series next to each other in the same chart?

Tags: altair

Let's assume our data frame has two series of type integer: `estimated_value` and `sell_price`.

I want to have two bars next to each other in the same bar chart. 
The left one shows `average(estimated_value)` and the right one shows `average(sell_price)`.
They shall share the same axis.

I thought this would be a very common use case but I could not find any example in the docs. All the examples use 'colour' or 'column' to group bars.

- I've tried using y2 but it seems to simply erase the difference to y1 instead of adding a second series.
- Then I tried using a layeredChart but this puts both bars on top of each other instead of next to each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you have wide-form data rather than long-form data. The difference is discussed in [Long-form vs. Wide-form data](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/data.html#long-form-vs-wide-form-data).

Once you've transformed your data to long-form, you can use standard encodings to achieve this result. Here's how it might look, using some example data:

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({
    'estimated_value': [500, 600, 700, 800, 900],
    'sell_price': [550, 610, 690, 810, 950]
})

alt.Chart(data).transform_fold(
    ['estimated_value', 'sell_price'], as_=['category', 'price']
).mark_bar().encode(
    y='category:N',
    x='average(price):Q',
)
```

[image]